# Agrupar registros repetidos em um array no javascript

Tags: javascript, array, ecmascript-6

Possuo um array em JS com somente dois atributos, um nome de estado e um nome de cidade.
Exemplo:

```
var variavel = [{estado: 'São Paulo', cidade: 'Campinas'},
                {estado: 'São Paulo', cidade: 'Santos'},
                {estado: 'São Paulo', cidade: 'Sorocaba'},
                {estado: 'Bahia', cidade: 'Salvador'},
                {estado: 'Bahia', cidade: 'Ilhéus'},
                {estado: 'Rio Grande do Sul', cidade: 'Porto Alegre'}];
```

Porém agora gostaria de agrupar as cidades por estado, eliminando informações repetidas, ficando dessa forma:

```
var variavel = [{estado: 'São Paulo', cidades: [{nome: 'Campinas'}, {nome: 'Santos'}, {nome: 'Sorocaba'}]},
                {estado: 'Bahia', cidades: [{nome: 'Salvador'}, {nome: 'Ilhéus'}]},
                {estado: 'Rio Grande do Sul', cidades: [{nome: 'Porto Alegre'}]}];
```

Qual a melhor forma forma de obter esse resultado?

Answer (score 2):

Eu abordaria o problema assim:

- um só objeto com uma chave para cada cidade
- iterar a array inicial para preencher esse objeto
- depois de ter um objeto como descrito gerar então uma array novamente caso necessário. Este ultimo passo seria dispensável, depende da utilização desse objeto.

Exemplo:

```js
const variavel = [{ estado: 'São Paulo', cidade: 'Campinas' }, { estado: 'São Paulo', cidade: 'Santos' }, { estado: 'São Paulo', cidade: 'Sorocaba' }, { estado: 'Bahia', cidade: 'Salvador' }, { estado: 'Bahia', cidade: 'Ilhéus' }, { estado: 'Rio Grande do Sul', cidade: 'Porto Alegre' } ];

const estados = variavel.reduce((obj, {estado, cidade}) => {
  if (!obj[estado]) obj[estado] = [];
  obj[estado].push(cidade);
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(estados)); // eu usaria este objeto

const outraVariante = Object.keys(estados).map(estado => {
  return {
    estado,
    cidades: estados[estado]
  };
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(outraVariante)); // como pedes na pergunta seria assim
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse algoritmo não é o melhor em questões de performance, mas traz o resultado esperado.

Para estados repetidos não serem adicionados separadamente, é verificado se não há um estado com o mesmo nome, caso haja, se adiciona a cidade do estado repetido no objeto que contém o estado já existente:

```js
var variavel = [
    {estado: 'São Paulo', cidade: 'Campinas'}, 
    {estado: 'São Paulo', cidade: 'Santos'}, 
    {estado: 'São Paulo', cidade: 'Sorocaba'}, 
    {estado: 'Bahia', cidade: 'Salvador'}, 
    {estado: 'Bahia', cidade: 'Ilhéus'}, 
    {estado: 'Rio Grande do Sul', cidade: 'Porto Alegre'}
    ];
var saida = [];

for (var i = 0; i < variavel.length; i++) {
    var cidadeIgual = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (saida[j] && variavel[i].estado == saida[j].estado) {
            saida[j].cidades.push({
                nome: variavel[i].cidade
            })
            cidadeIgual = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if (!cidadeIgual) {
        saida.push({
            estado: variavel[i].estado,
            cidades: [{
                nome: variavel[i].cidade
            }]
        })
    }
}

console.log(saida)
```